# MVC4 design pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns

I want to know which design patterns can be consumed with MVC4, moreover certain explanation is required with an example. In my case I have simple CRUD but its boring to write the same CRUD functionality over and over via entity framework by just changing dbcontext objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the repository-pattern.

Make an interface which declares your CRUD-operations, and give your entities a seperate implementation of this interface.

If you have entity "families" which have the same CRUD-implementations, you can write a generic implementation of the interface for that family of entities.